# Running attended installer inside docker windows/servercore

Tags: docker, installation, dockerfile, windows-server, windows-server-container

I've been attempting to move an application to the cloud for a while now and have most of the services set up in pods running in a k8s cluster. The last piece has been giving me trouble, I need to set up an image with an older piece of software that cannot be installed silently. I then attempted in my dockerfile to install its .net dependencies (2005.x86, 2010.x86, 2012.x86, 2015.x86, 2015.x64) and manually transfer a local install of the program but that also did not work.

Is there any way to run through a guided install in a remote windows image or be able to determine all of the file changes made by an installer in order to do them manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can track the changes done by the installer following these steps:

- start a new container based on your base image

```
docker run --name test -d <base_image>
```

- open a shell in the new container (I am not familiar with Windows so you might have to adapt the command below)

```
docker exec -ti test cmd
```

- Run whatever commands you need to run inside the container. When you are done exit from the container
- Examine the changes to the container's filesystem:

```
docker container diff test
```

You can also use `docker container export` to export the container's filesystem as a tar archive, and then `docker image import` to create an image from that archive.

Comment: The issue I'm having is installing something into the windows container. The software that must be installed on this image is only available in an attended installer.

Comment: My answer solves exactly that problem if you follow the steps.

Comment: The installer requires that you utilize the install gui, there are no command line arguments or prompts to run it.